# Is passing output from controller to model to view a violation of MVC?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, architecture

Let's say I want to output a message "hi". The string is created in the controller class, then passed to a handler in the model class, and then to an output function in the view class.

e.g.

```
class Controller:
  def __init__(self):
    self.model = Model()
  def myMessage(self):
    self.model.messageHandler('hi')

class Model:
  def __init__(self):
    self.view = View()
  def messageHandler(self, msg):
    self.view.display_my_message(msg)

class View:
  def display_my_message(self, message)
    print(message)
```

The "controller" never touches the view, but passing the string down the classes like that seems to be a bit disconcerting to me, since it's almost like I could've just typed `print('hi')` initially, which would obviously violated MVC principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a short way:

- **Controllers:** Deal with user requests, like clicking in a button (for desktop applications) or sending a form (for web)
- **Models:** Deal with data, how to represent, store and retrieve it.
- **Views:** Deal with the visual part, what the user really sees.

About your code, it is wrong, models should know **NOTHING** about views.

There are 2 main approaches for MVC: Passive and Active Model.

In the first one, the controller is the mediator between the data from the model and its representation in the view.

```
class Controller:
  def __init__(self):
    self.model = Model()
    self.view = View()
  def messageHandler(self):
    self.view.display_my_message(self.model.getMessage())

class Model:
  def __init__(self):
      pass
  def getMessage(self):
      return 'hi'

class View:
  def display_my_message(self, message)
    print(message)
```

In the second one, you use the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), when you can subscribe views to watch changes in the model. When a change is made, the model notifies its observers who can then take action.

```
class Controller:
  def __init__(self):
    self.model = Model()
  def messageHandler(self):
    self.model.putMessage('hi')

class Model:
  def __init__(self):
      self.subscribers = []
      self.message = ''

  def attach(subscriber):
      self.subscribers.append(subscriber)

  def notify():
      for s in self.subscribers:
          s.update()

  def putMessage(self, message):
      self.message = message
      self.notify()

  def getMessage(self):
      return self.message

class View:
  def update(self, message)
    print(message)
```

P.S.: I'm not used to programming in python, maybe there're some syntatic errors.

Comment: @Downvoters, mind comment?

Comment: @Pétur, thank's for editting

Answer (score -2):

It's definitely okay to pass a string to the Model; MVC is a layered architecture. In layered architectures, you can freely "move" from the Application layer (the controller) to the Domain layers (the model) underneath. Note that I am characterizing passing of a variable as a "move".

So:
You can call a function in the model from the controller with the variable.
    class controller
    {
      void method()
      {
        Model.call('yourstring');
      } 
    }

You should however not be moving up from the model to the controller.

Your model will do something with this string (possibly update itself) and in good ol' MVC, the change will trigger an event on the view.